Rosetta Destinations not showing Xcode 16
In Xcode 16 Rosetta option is not available,

Actually I'm facing some architectural issue in non rosetta simulators.
The code will run only Rosetta simulators.

could not find module 'module name' for target
'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'

In Xcode 15 it's available under Product -> Destination ->Destination Architecture.


Rosetta is not supported by Xcode. Ample warning of this was given long ago.

Once Mac and Xcode has restarted, the Rosetta simulators are now visible.
It's Under Product, select Destination > Show All Run Destinations to see Rosetta run destinations.

